# How to select a single element of database driven checkbox

Tags: html, angular, asp.net-web-api

here the item names are coming from the database, i want to select a single element but here i cant do it. canr someone help me?

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="roles">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let item of roles;let i = index">
                    <input type="checkbox" [id]="'roles-'+i" value="{{item.Id}}" checked]="item.selected"
                        (change)="updateSelectedRoles(i)">
                    <label [for]="'roles-'+i">{{ item.Name}}</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Aniket, I'm not sure I understood your question... Do you want to select one item from the backend or the frontend ? It's not clear... So the item names are stored in the database and you want to select only one from what the server send you back after your request, is that correct ?

Comment: @Sinan Hey Sinan, Thank you for your reply. I want to select only one option in the front end, the options are in a database table.  at present, there are three values in the database and in the frontend i can select all three but i want to select only one of the three values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" [id]="'roles-'+i" value="{{item.Id}}" [checked]="item.selected(change)="updateSelectedRoles(i)">
```

To this:

```
<mat-checkbox [id]="'roles-'+i" [value]="item.Id" [(ngModel)]="item.selected" (change)="updateSelectedRoles(i)"></mat-checkbox>
```